# How to get the lowest future time (after now) from list of times with the current time

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datetime, timespan

How to get the lowest future time, after the current time.

**Schedule Time** :

06.00

12.30

17.45

**Current Time**:

10.20

The Schedule time are in

```
List<TimeSpan> lstDT 

TimeSpan CurrentTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Ticks);

var min = lstDT
  .Select(x => new { 
     diff = Math.Abs((x - CurrentTimeSpan).Ticks), 
     time = x })
   .OrderBy(x => x.diff)
   .Last()
   .time;
```

Expected answer is 12.30 (since 12.30 is the next time **after** 10.20). 
*If the current time is 23:59 then the expected result is 6.00.*

Thanks

Comment: @CodeNotFound: this should be an answer. Could you post one?

Comment: @mjwills if the current time is 17.44 then the result should be 17.45.
if the time is 23.59 then the result should be 06.00

Comment: Whatever solution you choose, I'd suggest you test the 23:59 scenario.

Comment: All those exemple choose the next. Can you confirm that you want the closes and 6:20 for exemple return 6:00? Perhaps a little table with inspected input output will be a good [edit] for your question.

Comment: @rAm It is crucial that you provide a table as per DragandDrop's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see **4** issues with the current code; we have to

1. *Get rid* of *date part* (`TimeOfDay`)
2. *Change* `Last` into `First`
3. Be careful with *break of day*: `1:00` is closer to `23:59` than `22:00` (we have to analyze *two* values: difference and difference over the midnight)
4. Since we want *future* only we should drop `Math.Abs` (which makes past and future being equal) but put a condition

Implementation:

```
  List<TimeSpan> lstDT = new List<TimeSpan>() {
    new TimeSpan( 6,  0, 0), // pure times, no date parts
    new TimeSpan(12, 30, 0),
    new TimeSpan(17, 45, 0),
  };

  // Test Data:
  // DateTime current = new DateTime(2018, 10, 27, 11, 20, 0);
  // TimeSpan CurrentTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromTicks(current.TimeOfDay.Ticks);

  // TimeOfDay - we don't want Date part, but Time only
  TimeSpan CurrentTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Ticks);

  // closest future time
  var min = lstDT
    .Select(x => new {
       // + new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0) - over the midnight
       diff = x > CurrentTimeSpan 
         ? (x - CurrentTimeSpan).Ticks
         : (x - CurrentTimeSpan + new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0)).Ticks,
       time = x })
    .OrderBy(x => x.diff)
    .First()              // <- First, not Last
    .time;
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks a Ton.